# List all events for a job

Tags: kubernetes

I'm running `kubectl describe jobs JOBNAME` and I see the events listed, example below.

I want to get see a list of all events, not the aggregation I see below.

```
Events:
  Type    Reason            Age                   From            Message
  ----    ------            ----                  ----            -------
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  19m                   job-controller  Created pod: my-job-7r5th
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  19m                   job-controller  Created pod: my-job-plvxm
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  19m                   job-controller  Created pod: my-job-k6zng
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  19m                   job-controller  Created pod: my-job-9zrgc
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  19m                   job-controller  Created pod: my-job-qds4l
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  19m                   job-controller  Created pod: my-job-bzbr9
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  19m                   job-controller  Created pod: my-job-mng6t
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  19m                   job-controller  Created pod: my-job-6hzcm
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  19m                   job-controller  Created pod: my-job-4bswl
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  9m25s (x19 over 19m)  job-controller  (combined from similar events): Created pod: my-job-5s9v9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the events and grep for the object that you are looking for.

```sh
$ kubectl -n <namespace> get events | grep my-job-5s9v9
```

For example, I have a Redis StatefulSet running on my cluster and I want to find the vents on the pods:

```sh
$ kubectl get events | grep -e redis | grep pod
12m         Normal    SandboxChanged            pod/my-release-redis-master-0   Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
11m         Normal    Pulled                    pod/my-release-redis-master-0   Container image "docker.io/bitnami/redis:6.0.6-debian-10-r9" already present on machine
11m         Normal    Created                   pod/my-release-redis-master-0   Created container redis
11m         Normal    Started                   pod/my-release-redis-master-0   Started container redis
2m21s       Warning   BackOff                   pod/my-release-redis-master-0   Back-off restarting failed container
12m         Normal    SandboxChanged            pod/my-release-redis-slave-0    Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
11m         Normal    Pulled                    pod/my-release-redis-slave-0    Container image "docker.io/bitnami/redis:6.0.6-debian-10-r9" already present on machine
11m         Normal    Created                   pod/my-release-redis-slave-0    Created container redis
11m         Normal    Started                   pod/my-release-redis-slave-0    Started container redis
2m24s       Warning   BackOff                   pod/my-release-redis-slave-0    Back-off restarting failed container
12m         Normal    SandboxChanged            pod/my-release-redis-slave-1    Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
11m         Normal    Pulled                    pod/my-release-redis-slave-1    Container image "docker.io/bitnami/redis:6.0.6-debian-10-r9" already present on machine
11m         Normal    Created                   pod/my-release-redis-slave-1    Created container redis
11m         Normal    Started                   pod/my-release-redis-slave-1    Started container redis
2m33s       Warning   BackOff                   pod/my-release-redis-slave-1    Back-off restarting failed container
```

✌️

Comment: I guess that's the only way. It has a big caveat in that if you run the same job twice (job names are not uniquely identified as pod names are) then you'll get events for both jobs and not have a good way to distinguish between the two.